# AffectedRecords property is -1 but no changes in the table?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

I'm using MySql. I have a `DataReader`, I'm executing a sql query and I'm getting this result (it's my custom output):

> [CommandText: SELECT username, email FROM account;] [Type: Reader]
>   [IsAlive: True] [IsExecuted: True] [IsSucceeded: True] [Exception: ]
>   [AffectedRows: 0] [Scalar: False] [Reader: True] [RecordsAffected: -1]

As you can see, the sql query/command is "SELECT username, email FROM account;" but does deleting? I checked it and there were no changes in the table. What is it?

**EDIT 1:** Also look at this from MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.recordsaffected(v=vs.110).aspx

**EDIT 2:** *"Gets the number of rows changed, inserted, or deleted by execution of the Transact-SQL statement."*

So nothing changed, inserted or deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,

> nothing changed, inserted or deleted

during the `SELECT` command, as you didn't change anything, simply read the data from table.

Why should it delete something?

The reason for the value equal to `-1` is that during some **changes** like `UPDATE` or `DELETE`, this parameter will change from 0 to number of affected rows, but during select it's equal to some `NOT SET` value, which shouldn't be equal to a valid value like `0`.

Comment: I'm not expecting any changes. Why `AffectedRecords` property is -1 instead of 0?

Comment: Not a corrupt. AffectedRecords shouldn't being used in this case, and `-1` just a flag for this